# Convert serialized string to object or array

Tags: php, laravel, serialization

I have this following serialized string received by a Laravel Controller from an ajax call:

`"address=&city=&cp=&phone_domicile="` (it can be longer)

How can I convert it to a php Object or an Array using php or a Laravel helper function? to have this following:

```
address => ....,
city => .....,
phone_domicile => ....
```

Maybe it's an easy question but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parse_str`

```
$query = 'address=&city=&cp=&phone_domicile=';
parse_str($query,$queryStrToArray);
print_r($queryStrToArray);
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/Cg3qt

Comment: Please don't post answers to duplicate questions, if you think you have a new solution - post it to the duplicate attached to the question rather than here.

Comment: @NigelRen Noted.